# Regex with php, using preg_replace replecates input and nests it inside of a div

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to replace code-tags with divs that contain the classes I need.

I use JS to create the tags with a press of a button, this works fine, and I'm able to insert the tags as many times as I'd like.

```
code.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let val = contentBox.value + "\[code\]\[/code\]"  
    contentBox.value = val;
});
```

The problem only occurs when I'm trying to have php replace the tags.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QAOX.jpg) (can't post images seeing that I've yet to achive 10 reputation)
As you can see in the picture, the returned regex is completely off. I've read about preg_* functions and I've used [regex101](https://regex101.com) to look at the regex I parse. I'm not really sure what I've done wrong as I'm really new to regex.

```html
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" required> <br>
    <input type="file" name="postimage" placeholder="postimage" ><br>
    <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="category" required><br>
    <input type="button" id="code">Code</button>
    <input type="button" id="link">Link</button>
    <input type="button" id="test">Test</button>
    <textarea required placeholder="content" name="content" id="contentBox" style="height: 100px; width: 100%; resize: none;"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $content = $_POST["content"];
    $open = preg_replace('/\[code\]/i', '<div class="code">', $content);
    $close = preg_replace('/\[\/code\]/i', "</div>", $content);
    $code = preg_split('/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/m', $content);
}
```

I expect the output to have replaced the code-tags with the correct divs. And to ignore everything outside the code-tags.

Hope this all made any sense, if I've forgotten to include anything that might come in handy I'll do that upon request.

Comment: So... I'm going to be "that guy" and point out that anyone submitting `[/code][/code][/code]` probably just broke your entire site.

Comment: Yes, but the point of this tool is for people to write articles on their own sites(i.e portfolios). I couldn't imagine they would do that to themselves, but seeing that this could be a potential problem, I'll try and get around the edge cases.

Comment: One "easy" way is to use the `$count` parameter of the replacement functions, that will tell you how many replacements were done. If they don't match, stop.

Comment: That is excellent advice. I will look into it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seeing that I'm extremely slow... I just realized that I'd over complicated the entire thing and the solution was to simply use this

```php
$content = preg_replace('/\[code\]/s', "<div class='code'>", $content);
$content = preg_replace('/\[\/code\]/s', "</div>", $content);
```

Comment: Instead of preg_replace I think a str_replace might also work. You can omit the s in `/s`. It will make the dot match a newline but there are no dots in the pattern.

Comment: Excellent, I will do so. Will also look into str_replace. Thanks for taking your time :)